# R Tree with small dataset does not init the tree

Tags: r

**Summary**: I studied a simple Decision Tree example in R and to better learn I though i'll create a small example and see how does it look and Tree is not getting rendered. any advice will be great.

**Example**: Marks of 2 subjects for 10 students and data whether they have passed or failed

**Problem**: Generated tree, on print says too little about it

```
Conditional inference tree with 1 terminal nodes

Response:  did_pass_factor
Inputs:  marks1, marks2
Number of observations:  10
```

---

Code:

```
library(party)

# Marks for students
marks1 <- c(10, 80, 45, 96, 75, 12, 47, 12, 36, 85)
marks2 <- c(35, 70, 55, 80, 61, 34, 64, 18, 33, 99)

# Create a dataframe
dataset <- data.frame(marks1, marks2)

# Add more variables
dataset <- transform(dataset, did_pass = ifelse(marks1 > 40 & marks2 > 40, 1, 0))
dataset$did_pass_factor <- factor(dataset$did_pass)

head(dataset)

data_tree <- ctree(did_pass_factor~marks1+marks2, data=dataset)
data_tree
# Conditional inference tree with 1 terminal nodes
#
# Response:  did_pass_factor
# Inputs:  marks1, marks2
# Number of observations:  10

plot(data_tree)
```

**Update**:

**Why the doubt**:

When I run this sample code printing of `t` the tree, properly generates the tree. I am trying to find out why does it not work for my own example.

```
library(party)
iris$sp <- factor(iris$Species)

t <- ctree(sp~Sepal.Length, data = iris)
t
plot(t)
```

Comment: So what values do you want to print exactly? What do you want to be in the plot? It's unclear what your desired result is here.

Comment: > ref(dataset)
o [1:0x2213a194a10] <df[,4]> 
+-marks1 = [2:0x2213a4e8708] <dbl> 
+-marks2 = [3:0x2213a44ff88] <dbl> 
+-did_pass = [4:0x2213a4e9d08] <dbl> 
\-did_pass_factor = [5:0x221347900f8] <fct>

Comment: I have updated question of what is the doubt, ctree works fine with `iris` dataset. but not on my data set created by me. trying to understand why